# how to parse nested json array in java

Tags: java, json

I would like to parse netsted json in Java: Below is json string:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "empid": "12345",
        "details": {
            "name": "xyz",
            "age": "30",
            "sex": "M",
            "Address": {
                "Office": "office",
                "Home": "Home"
            }
        },
        "abcDetails": "asdf",
        "mobile": 123455
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "empid": "64848",
        "details": {
            "name": "eryje",
            "age": 3027,
            "sex": "M",
            "Address": {
                "Office": "office",
                "Home": "Home"
            }
        },
        "abcDetails": "fhkdl",
        "mobile": 389928
    }
]
```

I need **name, age** details from above json, can someone help how to parse these value in java, i tried the below code to get those value - it seems its nested and not sure how to get those value.

```
        JSONArray jsonarray = new JSONArray(str);
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject obj1 = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);

            String name = obj1.getString("name");
            String age = obj1.getString("age");

            System.out.println(name);
            System.out.println(age);
        }
```

Comment: so what is happening?

Comment: Why you dont try to parse JSON using this library: https://code.google.com/p/json-simple/. :)

Comment: @LeoAguilar Look like he is already using an library

Comment: I'm getting this exception - if I try to use getString("name") - org.json.JSONException: JSONObject["name"] not found.
 at org.json.JSONObject.get(JSONObject.java:498)
 at org.json.JSONObject.getString(JSONObject.java:669)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to use `#getJSONObject()` for getting nested object.

- But, this is my personal impression, why `org.json` package's version strings are date format ? Probably it's not good library...

Example:

```
package testing;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;

/**
 * Hello world!
 */
public class App {

    static String json = ""
 + "["
 + " {"
 + "     \"id\": 1,"
 + "     \"empid\": \"12345\","
 + "     \"details\": {"
 + "         \"name\": \"xyz\","
 + "         \"age\": \"30\","
 + "         \"sex\": \"M\","
 + "         \"Address\": {"
 + "             \"Office\": \"office\","
 + "             \"Home\": \"Home\""
 + "         }"
 + "     },"
 + "     \"abcDetails\": \"asdf\","
 + "     \"mobile\": 123455"
 + " },"
 + " {"
 + "     \"id\": 2,"
 + "     \"empid\": \"64848\","
 + "     \"details\": {"
 + "         \"name\": \"eryje\","
 + "         \"age\": 3027,"
 + "         \"sex\": \"M\","
 + "         \"Address\": {"
 + "             \"Office\": \"office\","
 + "             \"Home\": \"Home\""
 + "         }"
 + "     },"
 + "     \"abcDetails\": \"fhkdl\","
 + "     \"mobile\": 389928"
 + " }"
 + "]";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        JSONArray jsonarray = new JSONArray(json);
        System.out.println(String.format("JSONArray length => %d", jsonarray.length()));

        for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject obj1 = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
            JSONObject details = obj1.getJSONObject("details");
            System.out.println(String.format("details => %s", details.toString()));

            String name = details.getString("name");
            int age = details.getInt("age");
            System.out.println(name);
            System.out.println(age);
        }
    }
}
```

Results:

```
$ mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="testing.App"
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building testing 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] >>> exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:java (default-cli) @ testing >>>
[INFO]
[INFO] <<< exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:java (default-cli) @ testing <<<
[INFO]
[INFO] --- exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:java (default-cli) @ testing ---
JSONArray length => 2
details => {"sex":"M","Address":{"Home":"Home","Office":"office"},"age":"30","name":"xyz"}
xyz
30
details => {"sex":"M","Address":{"Home":"Home","Office":"office"},"age":3027,"name":"eryje"}
eryje
3027
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.576s
[INFO] Finished at: Fri Jul 17 10:46:29 JST 2015
[INFO] Final Memory: 7M/106M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Thanks you! It works. But I've scenario like some time i'll get the json without "details" object also.. Like below  - [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "empid": "12345",
        "details": {
            "name": "xyz",
            "age": "30",
            "sex": "M",
            "Address": {
                "Office": "office",
                "Home": "Home"
            }
        },
        "abcDetails": "asdf",
        "mobile": 123455
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "empid": "64848",
        "abcDetails": "fhkdl",
        "mobile": 389928
    }
]  In this case - how to handle it?

Comment: @learnjava See also javadoc of [#keys](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html#keys())  or [#has](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html#has(java.lang.String)). Probably, you should check JSON keys before getting it. If key doesn't exist, you call `continue` statement in for loop.

Answer (score 1):

The property name and age are in the details
Try this code

```
JSONArray jsonarray = new JSONArray(str);
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject obj1 = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
            JSONObject details = obj1.getJSONObject("details");
            String name = details.getString("name");
            String age = details.getString("age");

            System.out.println(name);
            System.out.println(age);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code your are doing

```
String name = obj1.getString("name");
```

but `name` is a sub-element of `detail` so you need to get the `detail` object first.

```
JSONObject detail = obj1.getJSONObject("details");
```

and then

```
String name = detail.getString("name");
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. But i've scenario sometime I wont receive "details" object like this - [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "empid": "12345",
        "details": {
            "name": "xyz",
            "age": "30",
            "sex": "M",
            "Address": {
                "Office": "office",
                "Home": "Home"
            }
        },
        "abcDetails": "asdf",
        "mobile": 123455
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "empid": "64848",
        "abcDetails": "fhkdl",
        "mobile": 389928
    }
] - How to handle this scenario

Comment: wrap in up in an try/catch block catching the `JSONException` see http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html#getJSONObject(java.lang.String)

Answer (score 0):

```
//import java.util.ArrayList;
//import org.bson.Document;

Document root= Document.parse("{\"records\":[\n" +
"    {\n" +
"        \"id\": 1,\n" +
"        \"empid\": \"12345\",\n" +
"        \"details\": {\n" +
"            \"name\": \"xyz\",\n" +
"            \"age\": \"30\",\n" +
"            \"sex\": \"M\",\n" +
"            \"Address\": {\n" +
"                \"Office\": \"office\",\n" +
"                \"Home\": \"Home\"\n" +
"            }\n" +
"        },\n" +
"        \"abcDetails\": \"asdf\",\n" +
"        \"mobile\": 123455\n" +
"    },\n" +
"    {\n" +
"        \"id\": 2,\n" +
"        \"empid\": \"64848\",\n" +
"        \"details\": {\n" +
"            \"name\": \"eryje\",\n" +
"            \"age\": 3027,\n" +
"            \"sex\": \"M\",\n" +
"            \"Address\": {\n" +
"                \"Office\": \"office\",\n" +
"                \"Home\": \"Home\"\n" +
"            }\n" +
"        },\n" +
"        \"abcDetails\": \"fhkdl\",\n" +
"        \"mobile\": 389928\n" +
"    }\n" +
"]}");


System.out.println((((Document)((ArrayList)root.get("records")).get(0)).get("id")));
System.out.println(((String)((Document)((ArrayList)root.get("records")).get(0)).get("empid")));
System.out.println(((String)((Document)((Document)((ArrayList)root.get("records")).get(0)).get("details")).get("name")));
System.out.println(((String)((Document)((Document)((ArrayList)root.get("records")).get(0)).get("details")).get("age")));
System.out.println(((String)((Document)((Document)((ArrayList)root.get("records")).get(0)).get("details")).get("sex")));
System.out.println(((String)((Document)((Document)((Document)((ArrayList)root.get("records")).get(0)).get("details")).get("Address")).get("Office")));
System.out.println(((String)((Document)((Document)((Document)((ArrayList)root.get("records")).get(0)).get("details")).get("Address")).get("Home")));
System.out.println(((String)((Document)((ArrayList)root.get("records")).get(0)).get("abcDetails")));
System.out.println((((Document)((ArrayList)root.get("records")).get(0)).get("mobile")));
System.out.println((((Document)((ArrayList)root.get("records")).get(1)).get("id")));
System.out.println(((String)((Document)((ArrayList)root.get("records")).get(1)).get("empid")));
System.out.println(((String)((Document)((Document)((ArrayList)root.get("records")).get(1)).get("details")).get("name")));
System.out.println((((Document)((Document)((ArrayList)root.get("records")).get(1)).get("details")).get("age")));
System.out.println(((String)((Document)((Document)((ArrayList)root.get("records")).get(1)).get("details")).get("sex")));
System.out.println(((String)((Document)((Document)((Document)((ArrayList)root.get("records")).get(1)).get("details")).get("Address")).get("Office")));
System.out.println(((String)((Document)((Document)((Document)((ArrayList)root.get("records")).get(1)).get("details")).get("Address")).get("Home")));
System.out.println(((String)((Document)((ArrayList)root.get("records")).get(1)).get("abcDetails")));
System.out.println((((Document)((ArrayList)root.get("records")).get(1)).get("mobile")));
```